# How do you access object value dynamically in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code which throws accessing error

```
const data = {
    name: 'Tox',
    age: 12,
    gender: "male"
};


Object.keys(data).map((key, i) => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}`, '|', `value: ${data[key]}`); // How do you get the value?
});
```

Edit:

Error message: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ name: string; age: number; gender: string; }' has no index signature.`

Comment: What's the error? Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The code works for Javascript, but not Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is accessed by `data[key]`, which you're doing correctly. I think the error that you're running into is not a JavaScript error but a TypeScript compiler error. Essentially, since `data` is not indexable with a `string` variable, you will need to let the compiler know that `key` is actually a keyof the `data` object, and not just a `string`:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}`, '|', `value: ${data[key as keyof typeof data]}`); // How do you get the value?
});
```

[See proof-of-concept example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDXMwIC2ApgFwwDkAKiAB4UA0OeCA5mTAIwBMTeM7MHGIAncgCJCCADbFxWAL4BuLFgDyAIwBWxYFAB0Aa2IBPCAApEyAJT6pAB3PGTaAHyZmoSCFn7pIVnMAA2dyABIMZwUghkoAH0YYIIA3GQBXDgirBABtZxgECBhnEAAzGCgTe2Iy+CQEAF1o6yUYAHo2mAAJEAB3eBAYExA0gWJYKAALYhhU6QyAfkUWrCA).

If you look at the `key` argument, TypeScript assumes that is simply a `string` instead of a property of the `data` object.